# Predicting in Stateful LSTMs

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I have the following Keras model, although it could be generalised to a normal RNN using GRUs.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(40, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1), stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
model.add(GRU(10, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, features), stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# Train model
iter = 10000
for i in range(iter):
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, nb_epoch=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, shuffle=False)
    if (i<(iter-1)):
        model.reset_states()

testPred = model.predict(testX,batch_size=batch_size)
print(mean_squared_error(testY,testPred))
```

If I don't have the `if` statement with regards to resetting the state, the mean squared error has always been higher. Considering that the **test set is right after the train set** wouldn't it make sense that you would want to preserve the state of the last memory block?

This tutorial seems to suggest otherwise: http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/ (i.e. he simply doesn't have that if statement, doesn't explicitly mention anything about keeping the last state).

So just wondering if I am correct about this.

Comment: I would say that if you want your network to generalize to other sequences too, you should not do that since there will be no initial state available for those sequences.